# sprite reset method not working in update thread(andengine)

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I am learning game development in android and for that I am using andenigne box2d extension.I have created 3 sprite arrays BarSet1,Barset2 and Barset3 each oh size 8.I have to move these arrays from right to left in circular looping fashion.After Barset3 I have start move again from Barset1 for this I am reseting my Barset1 by reset() method but the code is not working.I have spent almost a week for this glitch I dont know why its not working.Here my code:

**GameActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mygame;


import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.IUpdateHandler;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.IEntityModifier.IEntityModifierListener;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.LoopEntityModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.MoveXModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.ParallelEntityModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.AccelerationData;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.IAccelerationListener;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.modifier.IModifier;
import org.andengine.util.modifier.LoopModifier;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;

public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener{

    Scene scene;
    Bars BarClassObject;
    protected static int CAMERA_HEIGHT;
    protected static int CAMERA_WIDTH;
    BitmapTextureAtlas  BallTexture;
    ITextureRegion BallTextureRegion;
    BitmapTextureAtlas BarsTexture;
    ITextureRegion[] BarRegion=new ITextureRegion[4];
    Sprite[] BarSet1=new Sprite[8];
    Sprite[] BarSet2=new Sprite[8];
    Sprite[] BarSet3=new Sprite[8];
    int[] BarToX=new int[8];
    int[] BarFromX=new int[8];
    int ENDPOINT,SPRITE_WIDTH;
    PhysicsWorld physicsworld;
    Sprite ball;
    Body body;
    int i,j;
    static boolean IfGameJustStarted;
    //Body RedBarBody;
    int SameBargGap,DifferentBarGap;
    final MoveXModifier[] barMove=new MoveXModifier[8];
    final MoveXModifier[] barMove2=new MoveXModifier[8];
    final MoveXModifier[] barMove3=new MoveXModifier[8];

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        CAMERA_HEIGHT=display.getHeight();
        CAMERA_WIDTH=display.getWidth();

        Camera gameCamera=new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions options=new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED,new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT),gameCamera);
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)throws Exception 
    {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        BallTexture=new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),64,64,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        BallTextureRegion=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BallTexture, getAssets(),"ball.png",0,0 );
        BarsTexture=new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 64, 128);
        BarRegion[0]=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BarsTexture, getAssets(), "red.png",0,0);
        BarRegion[1]=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BarsTexture, getAssets(), "green.png",14,0);
        BarRegion[2]=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BarsTexture, getAssets(), "yellow.png",28,0);
        BarRegion[3]=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BarsTexture, getAssets(), "violet.png",42,0);
        BallTexture.load();
        BarsTexture.load();
        ENDPOINT=CAMERA_WIDTH;
        SPRITE_WIDTH=(int)BarRegion[0].getWidth();
        SameBargGap=(int)((int)(BallTextureRegion.getWidth())*2);
        DifferentBarGap=10;
        IfGameJustStarted=true;
        BarClassObject=new Bars();
        BarSet1=BarClassObject.CreateBarSet1Sprite(BarRegion,
                   ENDPOINT,CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                   this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
                   SameBargGap,
                   DifferentBarGap,
                   SPRITE_WIDTH);
        BarSet2=BarClassObject.CreateBarSet2Sprite(BarRegion,
                   ENDPOINT,CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                   this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
                   SameBargGap,
                   DifferentBarGap,
                   SPRITE_WIDTH); 
        BarSet3=BarClassObject.CreateBarSet3Sprite(BarRegion,
                   ENDPOINT,CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                   this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
                   SameBargGap,
                   DifferentBarGap,
                   SPRITE_WIDTH);

        BarToX=BarClassObject.getBarToX(ENDPOINT,SameBargGap,DifferentBarGap,SPRITE_WIDTH);
        BarFromX=BarClassObject.getBarFromX(ENDPOINT,SameBargGap,DifferentBarGap,SPRITE_WIDTH);
        for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
        {
            barMove[i]=new MoveXModifier(18.0f, BarFromX[i], (BarToX[i]+100),new IEntityModifierListener() {

                @Override
                public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                    for(int j=0;j<=7;j++)
                    {
                        BarSet1[j].reset();
                    }
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });
            barMove2[i]=new MoveXModifier(18.0f, BarFromX[i], BarToX[i]);

            barMove3[i]=new MoveXModifier(18.0f, BarFromX[i], BarToX[i]);
            //barMove[i].setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
            //barMove2[i].setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
            //barMove3[i].setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
        }
        for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
        {

            BarSet1[i].registerEntityModifier(barMove[i]);
            //BarSet2[i].registerEntityModifier(barMove[i]);
            //BarSet2[i].registerEntityModifier(barMove2[i]);
            //BarSet3[i].registerEntityModifier(barMove3[i]);
        }

        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)throws Exception 
    {
        scene=new Scene();  
        physicsworld=new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), true);    
        this.scene.setBackground(new Background(255, 23, 23));


        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception
    {
        ball=new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2,10,BallTextureRegion,this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        final FixtureDef BallFixture=PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f, 0.2f,0.0f);

        body=PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.physicsworld,ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, BallFixture);
        this.scene.attachChild(ball);
        physicsworld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, body, true, true));
        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.physicsworld);





        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler()
{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if((int)BarSet1[7].getX()==ENDPOINT)
                {
                    if(IfGameJustStarted)
                    {
                        for(int x=0;x<=7;x++)
                        {


                            BarSet2[x].registerEntityModifier(barMove2[x]);
                            //scene.attachChild(BarSet2[x]);
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {


                        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
                        {

                            BarSet2[i].reset();


                        }
                    }
                }
                else if((int)BarSet2[7].getX()==ENDPOINT)
                {
                    if(IfGameJustStarted)
                    {

                        for(int y=0;y<=7;y++)
                        {


                                BarSet3[y].registerEntityModifier(barMove3[y]);
                                //scene.attachChild(BarSet3[y]);


                        }
                    }
                        else
                        {

                            for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
                            {
                                BarSet3[i].reset();

                            }
                        }

                }
                else if((int)BarSet3[7].getX()==ENDPOINT)
                {
                    if(IfGameJustStarted)
                        IfGameJustStarted=false;


                            for(int z=0;z<=7;z++)
                            {

                                BarSet1[z].reset();



                            }






                }
                else{}
                /*End ENDPOINT LOGIC*/

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});

        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
         {
             scene.attachChild(BarSet1[i]);scene.attachChild(BarSet2[i]);scene.attachChild(BarSet3[i]);


         }



        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        body.applyForce(new Vector2(pAccelerationData.getX()*70, 0),body.getWorldCenter());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

**Bars.java**

```
package com.example.mygame;

import org.andengine.entity.modifier.MoveXModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObjectManager;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine;

public class Bars {

    int RedBar,GreenBar,YellowBar,VoiletBar;

    Sprite[] barset1=new Sprite[8];
    Sprite[] barset2=new Sprite[8];
    Sprite[] barset3=new Sprite[8];
    int[] barToX=new int[8];
    int[] barFromX=new int[8];
    public Bars()
    {


    }

    public Sprite[] CreateBarSet1Sprite(ITextureRegion Bars[],int ENDPOINT,int CAMERA_HEIGHT,VertexBufferObjectManager vbo,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH)
    {

    barset1[0]=new Sprite(ENDPOINT+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap, CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset1[1]=new Sprite(((int)barset1[0].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset1[2]=new Sprite(((int)barset1[1].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset1[3]=new Sprite((int)(barset1[2].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset1[4]=new Sprite((int)(barset1[3].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset1[5]=new Sprite((int)(barset1[4].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset1[6]=new Sprite((int)(barset1[5].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);
    barset1[7]=new Sprite((int)(barset1[6].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);
    //Sprite[   
        return barset1;
    }
    public Sprite[] CreateBarSet2Sprite(ITextureRegion Bars[],int ENDPOINT,int CAMERA_HEIGHT,VertexBufferObjectManager vbo,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH)
    {

    barset2[0]=new Sprite(ENDPOINT+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap, CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset2[1]=new Sprite(((int)barset2[0].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset2[2]=new Sprite(((int)barset2[1].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset2[3]=new Sprite((int)(barset2[2].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset2[4]=new Sprite((int)(barset2[3].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset2[5]=new Sprite((int)(barset2[4].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset2[6]=new Sprite((int)(barset2[5].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);
    barset2[7]=new Sprite((int)(barset2[6].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);

    //Sprite[   
        return barset2;
    }
    public Sprite[] CreateBarSet3Sprite(ITextureRegion Bars[],int ENDPOINT,int CAMERA_HEIGHT,VertexBufferObjectManager vbo,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH)
    {

    barset3[0]=new Sprite(ENDPOINT+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap, CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset3[1]=new Sprite(((int)barset3[0].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[0],vbo);
    barset3[2]=new Sprite(((int)barset3[1].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset3[3]=new Sprite((int)(barset3[2].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[1],vbo);
    barset3[4]=new Sprite((int)(barset3[3].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset3[5]=new Sprite((int)(barset3[4].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[2],vbo);
    barset3[6]=new Sprite((int)(barset3[5].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);
    barset3[7]=new Sprite((int)(barset3[6].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap), CAMERA_HEIGHT-((int)Bars[0].getHeight()), Bars[3],vbo);
    //Sprite[   
        return barset3;
    }
    public void resetBar(Sprite Barset[],int ENDPOINT,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH)
    {
        Barset[0].setX(ENDPOINT+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap);
        Barset[1].setX(Barset[0].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap);
        Barset[2].setX(Barset[1].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap);
        Barset[3].setX(Barset[2].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap);
        Barset[4].setX(Barset[3].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap);
        Barset[5].setX(Barset[4].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap);
        Barset[6].setX(Barset[5].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap);
        Barset[7].setX(Barset[6].getX()+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap);
    }
    public int[] getBarToX(int ENDPOINT,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH )
    {
        barToX[7]=0-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[6]=barToX[7]-SameBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[5]=barToX[6]-DifferentBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[4]=barToX[5]-SameBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[3]=barToX[4]-DifferentBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[2]=barToX[3]-SameBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[1]=barToX[2]-DifferentBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        barToX[0]=barToX[1]-SameBarGap-SPRITE_WIDTH;
        return barToX;

    }

    public int[] getBarFromX(int ENDPOINT,int SameBarGap,int DifferentBarGap,int SPRITE_WIDTH )
    {
        barFromX[0]=ENDPOINT+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap;
        barFromX[1]=barFromX[0]+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap;
        barFromX[2]=barFromX[1]+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap;
        barFromX[3]=barFromX[2]+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap;
        barFromX[4]=barFromX[3]+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap;
        barFromX[5]=barFromX[4]+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap;
        barFromX[6]=barFromX[5]+SPRITE_WIDTH+DifferentBarGap;
        barFromX[7]=barFromX[6]+SPRITE_WIDTH+SameBarGap;
        return barFromX;

    }

}
```